# $ is not defined error in firefox with jquery

Tags: jquery

I check that Firefox loads jquery. However I have an error telling, "$ is not defined" in firebug.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="going.js"></script>
```

And going.js has the following.

```
 if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $("body").addClass("chrome"); 

}
```

I tried  `$(document).ready(function(){ // my code here });`, but it gives the same error.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
http://jsbin.com/uwopi3/3/edit

Comment: Can you post your full html source code please?

Comment: I got a -1 too. Random down votes.

Comment: Nope, both for a question without the required code to help and an answer that relies on assumptions. (Didn't downvote myself tho)

Comment: updated with code here, http://jsbin.com/uwopi3/3/edit

Comment: @shin That code works as you can see. I get `<body class="chrome">` if I check on a chrome browswer. So you're probably not wrapping the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place both scripts just before closing `</body>` and your jQuery code right after.

**UPDATE**
Like i mentioned you need to place your code after your jQuery scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="going.js"></script>
  <script>
     if ($.browser.webkit) {
  $("body").addClass("chrome");
     }
</script>
```

Another thing you can do if this problem persists is use `jQuery.browser` instead of `$.browser` and see if it works. It may be a conflict between the plugin and jQuery script.

Comment: It would help if you post your html

Comment: But its working in my browser and in chrome it adds class to the body tag, bro!

Comment: I forgot to delete the going.js in the header. Thanks.