# jQuery is not defined error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am following a tutorial plus lesson on jQuery. In the video tutorial, the code is most likely the same but in Firefox at my end it's throwing `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` in the Firebug console.

This is my whole code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Day 1 jQuery</title>
        <style>
        li {color:blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 1</li>
            <li>List item 2</li>
            <li>List item 3</li>
            <li>List item 4</li>
            <li>List item 5</li>
        </ul>
        <srcipt src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var list = jQuery('ul li');
        console.log(list);
        });
        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I also looked at it but no help: [$ is not defined error in firefox with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604223/is-not-defined-error-in-firefox-with-jquery)

Tutorials link - https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: just a typo <srcipt> should read <script>

Comment: @Lilith2k3 yes very well pointed by destroy ..even Sublime text editor cracked at this point in signifying the error

Comment: Hence you mention Sublime2: There is a package "SublimeLinter", which I could really recommend. It does linting after each save :]

Comment: @Lilith2k3 thx bro for the info :) you can add this as answer as well..so that future visitors will be benefited too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
<srcipt
```

with

```
<script
```

But you shouldn't use jquery-latest in production : your code might break when jQuery changes. I suggest you point to a precise version.

Comment: thx a lot man..I am using Sublime text 2 editor and even this one failed with the wrong code..thx a lot..+1 and will accept in the time range

Comment: ohh I always thought that jquery-latest is the stable version link ..can you please share the link for precise version as I checked the repo but they are download links ..thx

Comment: @Trialcoder: http://jquery.com/download/ `-> Using jQuery with a CDN`

Comment: @FelixKling Thx..got it..just a thing...you guys are simply awesome!!! :) so much learning content here :)

Comment: @Trialcoder jquery-latest is stable, but that doesn't prevent functions from changing or being removed after a time. When you use another version, you need to test before you put it in production.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

```
<srcipt src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx bro for letting me know whr I was wrong:) +1

Answer (score 1):

To lessen Typos in Sublime, there is an excellent package: https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter